# How to scan range of tcp and udp ports at a time using nmap?

Tags: networking, nmap, port

I tried this command but its not scanning udp ports...

```
nmap --open -p T:22,25,53,80,111,443,465,587,953,993,995,3306,5666,8891,U:53,68,111,323,715 13.235.13.13
```

What is the correct way for scanning udp + tcp ports at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Nmap documentation portal](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html):

> Note that to scan both UDP and TCP, you have to specify -sU and at least one TCP scan type (such as -sS, -sF, or -sT). If no protocol qualifier is given, the port numbers are added to all protocol lists.

So you can use:

```
nmap --open -sT -sU -p T:22,25,53,80,111,443,465,587,953,993,995,3306,5666,8891,U:53,68,111,323,715 13.235.13.13
```